# How get list of all songs played in android phone

Tags: android, media-player, vlc, playlist

I want to get list of songs played in android **phone** so how can I get it?
Where does all other media player store their recently played data in an android **phone**?

Comment: hi, welcome to stack, In general here on stack the rule of thumb is that asker need to put some code or other relevant material to show his efforts  and then only people help  as it is easy after knowing the approach that is  being followed, otherwise the problem soution scope is too broad to answer

Answer (score -1):

Well when you are playing a song you must have the below information

1. Mp3 file name
2. Mp3 file path

Just store them in a DB with the current time of its Playing and a variable to check its count, like if your playing song again,just increment its count,which will give you the most played songs.

Comment: But how exactly name of file can be extract directly from media player ?

Comment: you wont get them from Media player,you need to load them from files